# Changing Anchor properties based on form size

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to change the size of a groupbox or panel etc. based the size of the form.
So if the user makes the window size bigger that it stretches just to a particilluar size and than groupbox should not get bigger. And if the windows gets smaller than the groupbox should shrink too.

Here is the code on what should happen but it doesn't work. It only works if I resize the form slowly but if I do it a bit faster than the groupbox gets buggy. Its on the SizeChange event.

Please help me, thank you all!

```
if (this.Width >= 1530)
{
    groupBox1.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right);
}
else if (this.Width <= 1530)
{
    groupBox1.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Left);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Originally from my comment:

> Leave it DOCKED to the RIGHT and get rid of that code. Select your
> GroupBox then set the MaximumSize and MinimumSize properties to
> appropriate values. If you don't want it to change height, then set
> the Y value to the current height it is now. This will allow it to
> grow/shrink up to that max/min width you specified while still
> allowing it to resize automatically to the in-between values due to
> the Anchor. – Idle_Mind